# How to output file to 2 different folders

Tags: batch-file

I want to ask how we output file to 2 different folders. Below is my code that only can output file to one folder. Any changes that I need to make so that it can output the file to 2 different folders?

Code :

```
)
echo "Hi";
)>"C:\Users\310152922\Desktop\AutomatedScript\Email\validateCOB.txt"
```

Folder name and file name:

```
1 : C:\Users\310152922\Desktop\AutomatedScript\Email\validateCOB.txt
2 : C:\Users\310152922\Desktop\AutomatedScript\Backup\validateCOB.txt
```

Expected output:

It able to create validateCOB.txt in to `Email` and `Backup` Folder. Currently it only able to output `validateCOB.txt` to `Email` folder.

Thanks for viewing, comments and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
)
echo "Hi";
)>"C:\Users\310152922\Desktop\AutomatedScript\Email\validateCOB.txt"

copy "C:\Users\310152922\Desktop\AutomatedScript\Email\validateCOB.txt" "C:\Users\310152922\Desktop\AutomatedScript\Backup\validateCOB.txt"
```

Comment: +1. Yes, there is not much to do except basic copy of result in vanilla CMD. You also can find Windows version of [tee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(Unix)) or consider PowerShell instead of cmd/bat files - PowerShell have its own [Tee-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849937.aspx)

Comment: Haha.. I love `copy`..easy easy!! Thank you so much fox!

Answer (score 2):

```
set "file.1=C:\Users\310152922\Desktop\AutomatedScript\Email\validateCOB.txt"
set "file.2=C:\Users\310152922\Desktop\AutomatedScript\Backup\validateCOB.txt"

    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%N in ('echo "HI"') do (
       (echo(%%N)>>%file.1%
       (echo(%%N)>>%file.2% 

    )
```

Comment: hmm, this is another method that more complex than `copy` but this is working too! Recommend to give it a try but I still prefer `copy`. Thank you Sir!